# Count Votes Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, count

Hy, i'm making a site were i have a page that have a number of dj's and i put a button in everyone to people vote.
However, i don't know how to count the votes and how to let people vote just once.
I put a different ID to each DJ like 0, 1, 2 ,3 to make my work easier. I tried a code but that doesn't count the right clicks, it just counts once and when i refresh the page, the count restarts at 0.
Here's the code i've made:

```
<script>
        function votos(dj){
            var deejays = new Array();
            if(dj == 0){
                deejays[0] = deejays[0] + 1;
                return deejays[0];
                alert("O DJ "+dj+" tem "+deejays[0]+" votos." );
            }else if(dj == 1){
                //deejays[1] = deejays[1] + 1;
                //return deejays[1];
                //alert("O DJ "+dj+" tem "+deejays[1]+" votos." );
                alert(dj);
                }

            }
      </script>
```

the alert is just to help me now.

Comment: The alert() comes after the return statement, so that will never run?

Comment: javascript is a client side language.  it wont keep state when the page refreshes.  If you hope to save your counts, you'll need to send the count to some serverside language (php, ruby, etc) to be processed and saved in a database of some kind

Comment: What do you meen after this code : deejays[0] = deejays[0] + 1;
It returns [NaN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of persistent backend store (like a database) to keep track of votes between the different site visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies to keep track of votes (insecure and falsifiable) or use a DB to keep track of votes per IP or user (or whatever criteria you need). You can't do that with just javascript.